# Macros Rookie Programmer

Tags: c++

I had a lab class this was the question can some one correct this program/it runs corretcly but when its output is wrong. It basically must print the smallest of the three conditions, here's the question:

> Write a program that defines a macros `minimum2` to determine the smaller of two numeric values. Then use minimum two to compare a third macros that should be define name minimum three to determine the smallest number.

This is the code I wrote, it has two errors code has no effect and `e` is assign a value that is never used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define minimum2(a,b)(a < b)?a:b
#define minimum3(a,b,c) minimum2(a,b) < c? minimum2(a,b):c

int main()
{
   int  c = 3, d = 4, e = 2;
   minimum3(c, d, e);
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Please help me I have a test soon and would be grateful for that.

Comment: Please format your code.  There are instructions and a `{}` button on the edit page.

Comment: You're not storing the result of your macro anywhere in main...

Comment: `(a < b) ? a : b < c ? (a < b) ? a : b : c` is what `minimum3` expands to.  Due to precedence, `b < c` will be evaluated, not `minimum2(a, b) < c`, so if `a < b` then `a` will be the result, whatever the value of `c`.  Macros suck, and I question the value of a C++ course that covers macros in any detail.

Answer (score 5):

1. You need more parentheses in your macro definitions.
2. You need to *use* the result of your `minimum3` operation somehow.

Answer (score 2):

`minimum2(a,b)` gets replaced by `(a < b) ? a : b` which means you should:

- put parentheses in the definition of first macro like this:
  `#define minimum2(a,b) ((a < b) ? a : b)`
- or put them everywhere you call `minimum2` like this:
  `#define minimum3(a,b,c) (minimum2(a,b)) < c ? (minimum2(a,b)) : c`

This is first mentioned option and works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define minimum2(a,b) ( (a < b) ? a : b )
#define minimum3(a,b,c) minimum2(a,b) < c ? minimum2(a,b) : c

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", minimum3(2, 3, 4));
    printf("%d\n", minimum3(3, 4, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2
2
```

Comment: @CarlNorum: Thanks, haven't noticed that one. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Looks good now.  I'd suggest fully-parenthesizing both macros to be sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

First off, macros are not functions, they are textual replacements. If a macro is to produce the min of two numeric value it should produce the numeric value and not some C++ expression.

Secondly the easiest way to do this is to use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html):

```
#define minimum2(a,b) BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_LESS(a,b), a, b)
#define minimum3(a,b,c) minimum2(minimum2(a,b), c)
```

This will accept literal numbers from 0 to 256. It won't accept variables. Macros don't understand variables. You have to write C++ functions to accept variables.

Answer (score -2):

```
 #define minimum2(a,b)((a) < (b))?(a):(b)
 #define minimum3(a,b,c) minimum2((a),(b)) < (c)? minimum2((a),(b)):(c)
```

and our course you need to output your results:

```
printf("m3:%d\n", minimum3(c, d, e));
```